# Is there something similar to g8 but shows the values according to the file encoding?

Tags: unicode, encoding

I am looking for a `g8` equivalent that prints the hex values of the character under the cursor according to the file encoding of the file loaded in a buffer rather than assuming it's utf-8.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible as near as I can figure out... Even piping characters to external programs (`xxd`, `hexdump`) seems difficult, since many functions don't seem to be multibyte-aware enough (at least not with BIG-5)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but the following mapping seems to do the trick.

```
" g9                Print the hex values of the bytes used in the
"                   character under the cursor / selected text, using the
"                   actual 'fileencoding' of the buffer.
function! s:ShowHexFileEncodingCharacter( isSelection )
    let l:text = (a:isSelection ? ingo#selection#Get() : ingo#text#GetChar(getpos('.')[1:2]))
    if empty(l:text)
        echomsg 'NUL'
        return
    endif

    let l:encoding = (empty(&l:fileencoding) ? &encoding : &l:fileencoding)
    let l:output = ingo#buffer#temp#Call(function('GetHexFileEncodingCharacters'), [l:encoding, l:text])
    let l:hex = substitute(l:output, '0a\%(00\)*$\|\%(00\)\+0a$', '', '') " Remove the encoding of the trailing LF.
    echomsg substitute(l:hex, '..\zs', ' ', 'g')
endfunction
function! GetHexFileEncodingCharacters( fileencoding, text )
    let [l:save_fileencoding, l:save_fileformat] = [&l:fileencoding, &l:fileformat]
    let [&l:fileencoding, &l:fileformat] = [a:fileencoding, 'unix'] " Always use Unix fileformat to make the removal of the newline easier.
    try
        silent call ingo#lines#PutWrapper(1, 'put', a:text)
        silent 1delete _
        %!xxd -ps -c 999
    finally
        let [&l:fileencoding, &l:fileformat] = [l:save_fileencoding, l:save_fileformat]
    endtry
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> g9 :<C-u>call <SID>ShowHexFileEncodingCharacter(0)<CR>
xnoremap <silent> g9 :<C-u>call <SID>ShowHexFileEncodingCharacter(1)<CR>
```

It uses the `:!` command to filter the character through the external `xxd` command (which ships with Vim and performs a hex dump). This uses some functions of my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, note that `ga` uses the `encoding` (not fileencoding) when it is a non-unicode encoding. You should be aware of the other consequences of setting `encoding` to a value other than utf-8, though.

The `encoding` setting is actually the internal encoding used in vim (almost always utf-8 these days - setting it to a different unicode encoding is interpreted as utf-8 as well) - it's used for buffer contents, variables, options, etc. Having it as something other than UTF-8 limits what characters you can have any of those places, and changing it while vim is running will change the meaning of any values (including buffer contents) that are already loaded with non-ASCII text. This also explains why `ga` and `g8` *normally* always return unicode and UTF-8 values - because the buffer is in `encoding` (= utf-8) regardless of what encoding the file was in.

Comment: What would those consequences be? Dire?

Comment: `encoding` is the internal encoding used for text strings everywhere in vim, so you cannot have any variables set that include characters not in the character set, load any files with characters it doesn't support, etc. Changing it mid-stream changes the meaning of any existing non-ascii values (including the contents of file buffers).

Comment: Interesting! Could you add that to the answer as well?